# Efficient algo for median of median

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

I have found so many articles regarding median of median but no where I find any satisfactory answer. My professor taught me regarding the topic in which he mentioned that we group the given array in size of 5 and find the medians of these groups . store them in another array and recursively do the previous step until we obtain a single group . The median of this group will be the median of the array and so it could be done in order of n time.

But I didn’t find the same in other text books and lectures .What is mentioned there is that the result divide the array into 30:70 ratio in worst case.

Comment: To make sure I understand the question - are you asking for confirmation that the “split into blocks of five, take the median of each, then take the median of those medians” approach is indeed one that works? Are you asking why that guarantees a 30/70 split? Something else?

Comment: @templatetypedef My doubt is whether this approach will result in the actual median of the input array or not.

Comment: No, it will not.  The median might not even be the median of any group of 5.  If your professor said this, then he's just wrong.  It's more likely that you misunderstood.  The procedure you've outlined also does not guarantee the 30:70 worst-case split.  The recursive call need to be a full quickselect in order for this to work right, and quickselect does return an accurate median.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice paper explaining all you want to know and more about median of median and real life improvements, as median of ninthers, was written by Andrei Alexandrescu

https://erdani.com/research/sea2017.pdf .